# Do goddesses and wives of any rishis wear the Yajñopaveetam (sacred thread)?

Tags: women, rishi, goddess, yagnopavitam

Male gods and other devas and sages, are all depicted wearing the sacred thread in their images or murtis.
And, the scriptures too describe their form (in the dhyana-shlokas) with a sacred thread.

What about the female counterparts of devas, do all of them wear the sacred thread (janeu)?

What about the wives of great sages like the sapta rishis?

**More importantly, is there any specific mention of any, or all the tridevis wearing a Yajñopaveetam?**

Overall, does the female denizens of the worlds, "higher" than Bhuloka, are said to be wearing the sacred thread in any canonical text?

<sup>Related, but not a duplicate of: [Does Devi wear the sacred thread? And do any dhyana shlokas of her mention her wearing it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42783/does-devi-wear-the-sacred-thread-and-do-any-dhyana-shlokas-of-her-mention-her-w), which is specifically asking about a particular goddess only, and not in general like this question.</sup>

Comment: This is partially duplicate. You should instead asked for wives of Rishis alone and answered it in other question.

Comment: No it's not. That question asks about the Devi. By Devi, generally the Supreme Goddess of Shakta sect is implied, which by corollary implies Uma or. Parvati. My question has tridevis and other sacred females also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that as per the Skanda Purāṇa, atleast some goddesss and river deities do wear a Yajñopaveetam.

1. Goddess Sarasvati (one of the tridevis) is described wearing a Yajñopaveetam.

   - Goddess Sarasvati (Savitri) is described as wearing a white sacred thread in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa

> Skandamahāpurāṇam [5.3.200](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425929.html)
>
> बाला बालेन्दुसदृशी रक्तवस्त्रानुलेपना । उषःकाले तु ध्यातव्या सन्ध्या
> सन्धान उत्तमे ॥ २००.७ ॥ उत्तुङ्गपीवरकुचा सुमुखी शुभदर्शना ।
> सर्वाभरणसम्पन्ना श्वेतमाल्यानुलेपना ॥ २००.८ ॥
> **श्वेतवस्त्रपरिच्छन्ना श्वेतयज्ञोपवीतिनी** ।
>
> > - 7-9,a. In the course of the excellent Sandhyā meditation early in the morning, Sāvitrī is to be imagined and meditated upon in the form of a
> >   girl resembling the crescent moon, with red garments and red unguents.
>
> > - At midday Sāvitrī should be imagined and meditated upon as a
> >   sweet-faced, auspicious-looking, young woman with large and protruding
> >   breasts, richly adorned with all ornaments and wearing white garlands
> >   and unguents. **She is wearing white clothes and has white Yajñopavīta
> >   (sacred thread).**

---

2. Also in another section of the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa [5.3.13](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425742.html), the River deity Reva (Narmada) is described as wearing a python as her Yajñopaveetam.

> एवमुक्त्वा ऋषीव्रेवा प्रविवेश जलं ततः । करात्तशूला सा देवी
> **व्यालयज्ञोपवीतिनी** ॥ ३१ ॥
>
> > After saying this to the sages, Revā, that Divinity who had grasped a
> > trident with her hand and **who had the python serving as a sacred
> > thread,** entered the water.
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed it's rare for female divinities to sport a *yajñopavītam*, but not impossible within the Tāntrika sphere. Here are some examples

1. *Dakshiṇakālī*

> अञ्जनाद्रिनिभां देवीं करालवदनां शिवां । मुण्डमालावलीकीर्णां मुक्तकेशीं स्मिताननां ।। महाकालहृदम्भोजस्थितां पीनपयोधरां । विपरीतरतासक्तां घोरदंष्ट्रां शिवैः सह ।। **नागयज्ञपवीताढ्यां** चन्द्रार्धकृतशेखरां । सर्वालङ्कारसंयुक्तां मुण्डमालाविभूषितां ।। मृतहस्तसहस्रैस्तु बद्धकाञ्चीं दिगंशुकां । शिवाकोटीसहस्रैस्तु योगिनीभिर्विराजितां । रक्तपूर्णमुखाम्भोजां मद्यपानप्रमत्तिकां ।। वह्न्यर्कशशिनेत्राञ्च रक्तबिस्फुरिताननां । विगतासुकिशोराभ्यां कृतकर्णाबतंसिनीं ।। कण्ठाबसक्तमुण्डालीगलद्रुधिरचर्चितां । श्मशानवह्निमध्यस्थां ब्रह्मकेशववन्दितां ।। सद्यःकृतशिरःखड़्गवराभीतिकराम्वुजां । [As quoted in *Brihat Tantrasāra*]

2. *Chinnamastā*

> स्वनाभौ नीरजं ध्यायेच्छुद्धं विकसितं सितं । तत्पद्मकोषमध्ये तु मण्डलः चण्डरोचिषः ।। जपाकुसुमसङ्काशं रक्तवन्धुकसन्निभं । रजःसत्त्वतमोरेखायोनिमण्डलमण्डितं ।। मध्ये तु तां महादेवीं सूर्यकोटिसमप्रभां ।। छिन्नमस्तां करे वामे धारयन्तीं स्वमस्तकं । प्रसारितमुखीं भीमां लेलिहानाग्रजिह्विकां ।। पिवन्तीं रौधिरीं धारां निजकण्ठविनिर्गतां । विकीर्णकेशपाशाञ्च नानानपुष्पसमन्वितां ।। दक्षिणे च करे कर्त्रीं मुण्डमालाविभूषितां । दिगम्बरीं महाघोरां प्रत्यालीढ़पदस्थितां ।। अस्थिमालाधरां देवीं **नागयज्ञपवीतिनीं** । रतिकामोपविष्टाञ्च सदा ध्यायन्ति मन्त्रिनः ।। सदा षोड़शवर्षीयां पीनोन्नतपयोधरां । विपरीतरतासक्तौ ध्यायेद्रतिमनोभवौ ।। डाकिनीवर्णिनीयुक्तां वामदक्षिणयोगतः । देवीगलोच्छलद्रक्तधारापानं प्रकुर्वतीं ।। वर्णिनीं लोहितां सौम्यां मुक्तकेशीं दिगम्वरां । कपालकर्तृकाहस्तां वामदक्षिणयोगतः ।। **नागयज्ञपवीताढ्यां** ज्वलत्तेजमल्लीमिव । प्रत्यालीढ़पदां दिव्यां नानालङ्कारभूषितां ।। सदा षोड़शबर्षीयामस्थिमालाविभूषितां । डाकिनी वामपार्श्वस्थां कल्पसूर्यानलोपमां ।। विद्युज्जटां त्रिनयनां दन्तपंक्तिवलाकिनीं । दंष्ट्राकरालवदनां पीनोन्नतपयोधरां ।। महादेवीं महाघोरां मुक्तकेशीं दिगम्बरां । लेलिहानमहाजिह्वां मुण्डमालाविभूषितां ।। कपालकर्तृकाहस्तां वामदक्षिणयोगतः । देवीगलोच्छलद्रक्तधारापानं प्रकुर्वतीं ।। करस्थितकपालेन भीषणेनातिभीषणां । आभ्यां निषेव्यमानां तां ध्यायेद्देवीं विचक्षणः ।। [As quoted in *Brihat Tantrasara*]

3. *Mahādurgā*

> सिंहस्कन्धसमारूढ़ां नानालङ्कारभूषितां । चतुर्भुजां महादेवीं **नागयज्ञपवीतिनीं** ।। शङ्खशार्ङ्गसमायुक्तवामपाणिद्वयान्वितां । चक्रञ्च पञ्चवाणांश्च दधतीं दक्षिणे करे ।। रक्तवस्त्रपरिधानां वालार्कसदृशीतनुं । नारदाद्यैर्मुनिगणैः सेवितां भवसुन्दरीं ।। त्रिवलीवलयोपेतनाभिनालमृणालिणीं । रत्नद्वीपे महाद्वीपे सिंहासनसमन्विते । प्रफुल्लकमलारूढ़ां ध्यायेत्तां भवगेहिनीं ।। [Quoted in *Brihat Tantrasāra*]

4. *Brahmāṇī*

> हंसासनसमारूढ़ा रक्तवर्णा चतुर्मुखा । पिचिण्डिला निम्ननाभिः **शुक्लयज्ञोपवीतिनी** ।। स्थूलगण्डाधोरौष्ठभ्रूकपोलवदनात्माका । बद्धपद्मासना स्थूला घनपिङ्गशिखाजटा ।। सप्तर्षिभिर्नारदाद्यैः स्तूयमाना परेश्वरी । वाहुभ्यां दक्षवामाभ्यामक्षसूत्रं कमण्डलुं ।। धारयन्ती मुखैर्वेदान्पठन्ती खर्वविग्रहा । चिन्तनीयेदृशी देवी ब्रह्माणी सर्वकामदा । [*Mahākālasaṁhitā:Kāmakalākhaṇda*]

5. *Māheshvarī*

> हिमानीशैलसंकाशामतिपीतजटाभरां । घनाघनाभनागेन्द्रपरिबद्धजटाचयां ।। जटाजूटोच्छलद्गङ्गाजलकल्लोलमालितां । पञ्चवक्त्रां गलच्छायाजितकज्जलरोचिषं ।। हिमांशुशकलोद्दीप्तपञ्चभालां हसन्मुखीं । प्रतिभालप्रविद्योतित्रित्रिलोचनसंगतां ।। भालतृतीयनेत्रद्यद्वह्निज्वालासमाकुलां । कपोलमण्डलोद्योतिशुद्धस्फटिककुण्डलां ।। **शुभ्रवासुकिनागेन्द्रलसद्यज्ञोपवीतिनीं** । शातकुम्भाभनागेन्द्ररुचिराङ्गदशोभितां ।। अतिशोनभुजङ्गेन्द्रविलसद्रत्नकङ्कणां । वसानां चर्म वैयाघ्रं रत्नाकल्पोल्लसत्तनुं ।। माहेश्वरीं समारुढ़ामतिश्वेतबृषोपरि । दशवाहुं वीरभद्रनन्दिभृङ्गीपुरःसरां ।। विष्णुरूपं शवं त्रिशूलं परशुमेव च । अक्षमालां वरं दक्षे करे संविभ्रतीं परां ।। पिनाकं नागपाशं च मृगं डमरुमेव च । अभयं दधतीं वामे प्रमथादिर्गणैर्वृतां ।। [*Mahākālasaṁhitā:Kāmakalākhaṇda*]

Comment: It's not rare for female divinities to wear sacred thread. As shown in my answer.